# Gitlab-CI backup lost by restarting Docker desktop

Tags: docker, gitlab, backup

I have a docker desktop installed on my windows pc. In that, I have self-hosted gitlab on one docker container. Today I tried to back up my gitlab by typing the following command:

```
docker exec -t <my-container-name> gitlab-backup create
```

After running this command the backup was successful and saw a message that backup is done. I then restarted my docker desktop and I waited for the container to start when the container started I accessed the gitlab interface but I saw a new gitlab instance.

I then type the following command to restore my backup:

`docker exec -it <my-container-name> gitlab-backup restore`

But saw the message that:

*No backups found in /var/opt/gitlab/backups*

*Please make sure that file name ends with _gitlab_backup.tar*

What can be the reason am I doing it the wrong way because I saw these commands on gitlab official website.

I have this in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.6" 
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce'
    container_name: 'gitlab'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://localhost:9090'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
    networks:
      - gitlab-network
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '9090:9090'
      - '2224:22'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'

networks:
  gitlab-network:
    name: gitlab-network
```

I used this command to run the container:

`docker-compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit`

Answer (score 0):

If you started your container using Volumes, try looking at `C:\ProgramData\docker\volume` for your backup.

The backup is normally located at: `/var/opt/gitlab/backups` within the container. So hopefully you mapped `/var/opt/gitlab` to either a volume or a bind mount.

Comment: I tried to locate this path but I am unable to find it in my windows.

Comment: Can you give the `docker run` command or the `docker-compose.yml` you used to start the container?

Comment: I have now added the compose file and the docker run command in the question please read.

Comment: First, try `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` and `ls /var/opt/gitlab/backups`. Is there a tar file?

Comment: I have tried this but got this ```ls: cannot access '/var/opt/gitlab/backups': No such file or directory```.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try supplying the name of the backup file, as for the omnibus install? When I've restored a backup in Docker, I basically use the omnibus instructions, but use docker exec to do it. Here are the commands I've used from my notes.

```
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-ctl stop unicorn  
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq  
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1541603057_2018_11_07_10.3.4 
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-ctl start  
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake gitlab:check SANITIZE=true
```

It looks like they added a gitlab-backup command at some point, so you can probably use that instead of gitlab-rake.